# How can I use LINQ / C# to pivot a list of ObjectA with an ObjectB so that I return a list of ObjectB, each with its own list of ObjectA

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry, I asked a similar question to this a moment ago but I realised I got things the wrong way around...

I have a list of object A and within this list is a property that is of type object B. Object B in turn contains a list of Object A.

So here are my two classes:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Other redacted properties that also need to be returned]
    public int ObjectBId { get; set; }
    public ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Other redacted properties that also need to be returned]
    public List<ObjectA> ObjectA { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a list of ObjectA, each with an ObjectBId/ObjectB, where some of those ObjectBs might be shared between ObjectAs, how can I pivot this list so that I can return a list of distinct ObjectB, each with their own list of ObjectA.

For example, if I have a list of ObjectAs like so:

| Id | ObjectBId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

How can I return a list of 2 ObjectBs, where ObjectB 1 has a list with one ObjectA (Id: 1) and ObjectB 2 has a list with two ObjectAs (Ids: 2 + 3). I need to return all the properties associated with ObjectA, not just the ID.

My attempt to include reproducible code for the set up of ObjectA list:

```
List<ObjectA> listObjectA = new List<ObjectA>
{
    new ObjectA { Id = 1, Name = "ObjectA1", ObjectBId = 1, ObjectB = new ObjectB { Id = 1, Name = "ObjectB1" } },
    new ObjectA { Id = 2, Name = "ObjectA2",  ObjectBId = 2, ObjectB = new ObjectB { Id = 2, Name = "ObjectB2" } },
    new ObjectA { Id = 3, Name = "ObjectA3",  ObjectBId = 2, ObjectB = new ObjectB { Id = 2, Name = "ObjectB2" } },
};
```

Comment: "For example, if I have a list of ObjectAs like so" - it would be more helpful to provide these in the form of *code*, a [mcve], so that if we want to test a solution, we can do so without having to write the example code ourselves as well. (In an ideal world, a question like this should contain everything required so that someone can copy/paste/edit/compile/run, *just* filling in the code that is the core of the answer.)

Comment: "This is data stored in an SQL database" - so are you looking for an answer that does this in SQL (in which case we need to know which LINQ provider you're using) or in LINQ to Objects?

Comment: I've added some code to set up an example of the list I'm referring to, is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear but I don't entirely understand your second comment. I'm getting the data from an SQL server database via my database context and then trying to use LINQ to manipulate it into the format I want which I then send to my page in my own defined DTO objects.

Comment: Right, so you're not wanting to issue a query against a `DbContext` or similar? That's fine - it sounds like the database side of things is basically irrelevant. It's worth bearing in mind that part of the point of LINQ is to allow you to express queries which aren't actually executed directly in .NET itself, but translated into SQL etc. So when you mention a database in the context of LINQ, that's a natural consideration.

Comment: @HannahHayes post the actual EF Core code then. EF Core will populate `ObjectB.ObjectA` by itself is you use `Include` though, eg `context.ObjectAs.Include(a=>a.ObjectB)`. And if you use `context.ObjectBs.Include(b=>b.ObjectA)` it will return a list of Bs with ObjectA populated

Comment: If you've already loaded `context.ObjectAs.Include(a=>a.ObjectB)` you can use `SelectMany` to get all Bs, eg `theAs.SelectMany(a=>a.ObjectB)`. EF had already populated `ObjectB.ObjectA` when it loaded the objects, so nothing more needs to be done

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The reason I was choosing to get the lists of ObjectA and B separately from the database is because both objects have a large number of additional objects against them and the number of Include...ThenIncludes I was having to use when getting them as a single list seemed to make the query very slow. It appears to be quicker to get them as two separate lists from the database.

Comment: You didn't say you were loading them separately. That's the actual problem. Until now you haven't posted any EF Code. What you did post has no relation to the question. First of all, make sure the relation fields are indexed. Then use `.Include(a=>a.ObjectBs).AsSplitQuery()`. The [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries) tells EF to use separate queries to load related entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on your verbal requirements/description. i created a prototype.
for each B object, there is a list of A-objects (the B3 object would be empty in example, because there is no relation )

```
void Main()
{
    var lstA = new List<ObjectA>(){
        new ObjectA(){Id = 1, Name = "A 1", ObjectBId = 1},
        new ObjectA(){Id = 2, Name = "A 2", ObjectBId = 2},
        new ObjectA(){Id = 3, Name = "A 3", ObjectBId = 2}
    };
    var lstB = new List<ObjectB>(){
        new ObjectB(){Id = 1, Name = "B 1"},
        new ObjectB(){Id = 2, Name = "B 2"},
        new ObjectB(){Id = 3, Name = "B 3"}
    };

    lstB.Select(b => new {
        ID = b.Id,
        Name = b.Name,
        ListOfObjectA = lstA.Where(w=> w.ObjectBId == b.Id).ToList()})
    .Dump();
}

public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public int ObjectBId { get; set; }
    public ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public List<ObjectA> ObjectA { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`GroupJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-8.0).  Something like:

```
class ObjectA
{
    //...
    public int SharedKey { get; set; }
}
class ObjectB
{
    //...
    public int SharedKey { get; set; }
}
List<ObjectA> aList = GetListOfA();
List<ObjectB> bList = GetListOfB();

var resultAWithListOfB = aList.GroupJoin(bList, a => a.SharedKey, b => b.SharedKey, (a, listOfB) => new { ObjectA = a, ListOfB = listOfB });
var resultBWithListOfA = bList.GroupJoin(aList, b => b.SharedKey, a => a.SharedKey, (b, listOfA) = new { ObjectB = b, ListOfA = listOfA });
```

Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a one-to-many relation between `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`: Every `ObjectB` has zero or more `ObjectAs`, every `ObjectA` belongs to exactly one `ObjectB`, namely the `ObjectB` that property `ObjectBId` refers to.

Quite often, when you have a one-to-many relation between to items: Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, or, as in your case, ObjectBs with their ObjectAs, there are two kinds of queries you use quite often:

- Give me a list of all Students, each Student with the School he attends. Give me a list of all ObjectAs, each with the ObjectB that this object belongs to: use `JOIN`
- Or the other way round: Give me a list of all Schools, each School with the Students who attend this School. Give me a list of all ObjectBs, each ObjectB with the ObjectA that belongs to this ObjectB (=where the foreign key refers to): use `GroupJoin`

In your case, you want *a list of items, each item with the things that belong to this item*. You need to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-8.0), or if you are fetching the data from a Database Management System, use [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=net-8.0).

Quite often I want to specify exactly the format in which I want to fetch the information, so I use the overload that has a parameter `resultSelector`

**Requirement:**
Fetch all (or some) properties of all ObjectBs, each with all (or some) properties of all ObjectAs that belong to this ObjectB (= where the foreign key refers to)

How about this:

```
IQueryable<ObjectB> objectBs = ...      // if the data is local use IEnumerable
IQueryable<ObjectA> objectAs = ...

// GroupJoin ObjectBs with their ObjectAs:
var ObjectBsWithTheirObjectAs = objectBs.GroupJoin(objectAs,
    objectB => objectB.Id,          // from each objectB take the primary key
    objectA => objectA.ObjectBId,   // from each objectA take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every objectB,
    // each with the zero or more objectAs that refer to this objectB
    // make one new:
    (objectB, objectAsThatBelongToThisObjectB) => new
    {
        // Select the properties of objectB that you plan to use
        Id = objectB.Id,
        Name = objectB.Name,
        ... // etc, other ObjectB properties

        // The ObjectAs that belong to this ObjectB:
        ObjectAs = objectAsThatBelongToThisObjectB.Select(objectA => new
        {
            // Select only the objectA properties that you plan to use
            Id = objectA.Id,
            Name = objectA.Name,
            ... // etc

            // not needed, you already know the value
            // ObjectBId = objectA.ObjectBId,
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

> LINQ queries are easier to read if you use plural nouns for collections and singular nouns for elements in the collection.

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ...
IQueryable<Order> orders = ...

var result = customers.GroupJoin(orders,
    customer => customer.Id,
    order => order.CustomerId,

    // resultSelector: for each customer with all his orders make one new
    (customer, ordersOfThisCustomer) => new {...});
```

### Why it is better to use resultSelector

Database Management Systems are extremely optimized for combining tables and selecting data. The transfer of the selected data is the slowest part of the query.
Hence it is wise to limit the data to the items that you actually plan to use.

If you have a database "Schools with their Students", then you know that every Student has a foreign key to the School that he attends.

You could fetch "School [10] with all his 2000 Students" without using the overload of GroupJoin that has a parameter resultSelector, like this:

```
var result = schools.Where(school => schoolId == 10)
    .GroupJoin(students,
        school => school.Id,          // from School take the primary key
        student => student.SchoolId);  // from Student take the foreign key to School
```

This would also give you School [10] with its Students. But apart from that you might transfer properties that you don't plan to use, you would also transfer the value [10] of the foreign key 2000 times, while you already know that it will be [10]. What a waste of processing power!

### Using Entity Framework?

I see the following code:

```
class ObjectA
{
    ...
    public int ObjectBId { get; set; }
    public ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    ...
    public List<ObjectA> ObjectA { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me the impression that you are using entity framework. A slight alteration of your classes would simplify your code quite a bit.

```
public class ObjectB
{
    ...
    // every ObjectB has zero or more ObjectAs (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectA> ObjectAs { get; set; }
}

class ObjectA
{
    ...

    // every ObjectA belongs to exactly one ObjectB, using foreign key
    public int ObjectBId { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}
```

Two changes: I made the properties that refer to the relation between the tables virtual and I changed the `List<ObjectA>` into `ICollection<ObjectA>`

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The relations between tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...) are represented by virtual properties.

Property `ObjectA.ObjectB` represents that every ObjectA belongs to exactly one ObjectA, hence it is virtual. The foreign key `ObjectA.ObjectBId` is a real column in the table, hence it is non-virtual

I also changed the List into an ICollection. The change to a Collection is to prevent you from using `ObjectAs[4]`. This has no defined meaning. Furthermore I used the interface, so I let entity framework decide what's the best type of object to return the sequence. Maybe it is a List, but it could also be that entity framework prefers to return an array, or let's go crazy: put all items in a Dictionary with the primary key as index for fast retrieval. `ICollection<...>` has all functionality that you possibly might want to use with the fetched data. The only thing you can't do is use the index. But, as said before: the index isn't defined.

### The Query is easier with entity framework

When entity framework is properly installed, you can specify the query while using the virtual properties:

**Requirement:**
Fetch all (or some) properties of all ObjectBs, each with all (or some) properties of all ObjectAs that belong to this ObjectB (= where the foreign key refers to)

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = dbContext.ObjectBs.Select(objectB => new
    {
        Id = objectB.Id,
        Name = objectB.Name,
        ...

        ObjectAs = objectB.ObjectAs.Select(objectA => new
        {
            Id = objectA.Id,
            Name = objectA.Name,
            ...
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();

    ... // process the fetched data
}
```

Note that using the virtual properties feels more intuitive?